# rails_admin filter data based on role

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, cancan, rails-admin, cancancan

My `rails_admin` application is having two roles namely `Teacher` and `Student` such that every user `belongs_to` a role. I am using the `gem cancancan` to manage roles.

*app/models*

```
class Role < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :users
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :role
    has_many :projects
end

class Project < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :user
end
```

*`Project` schema*

```
create_table "projects", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "description"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_projects_on_user_id", using: :btree
  end
```

Now, I want the project list to show all the data when `role` is `Teacher` but it should only show those projects where `project.user_id == user.id` when the `role` is `Student`.

That is, the final aim is to allow the `role` `Student` to see only his/her own projects thereby restricting the `role` `Student` to see all the projects where as the `role` `Teacher` should be able to see all the projects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get data based on current `user` role I made the following changes to `models/ability.rb`.

Under the case when user `role` is `Student`

```
can :read, Project, ["user_id = ?", user.id] do |project|
    project.present?
end
```

It will compare the `user_id` in `projects` table with the `user.id`  so, in case of `role` `Student` it will only fetch the projects created by that student.

Answer (score 0):

Your controller will have an action to list projects.
Just use a `before_action` filter to load projects based on role. 
Assuming, you are setting current_user in application's base controller and have association b/w student and project - student has_many projects.

```
ProjectController
  before_action :load_projects, only: [:index]

  def index
    @projects
  end

  private
  def load_projects
    if current_user.role == "Teacher"
      @projects = Project.all
    elsif current_user.role == "Student"
      @projects = current_user.projects
    end
  end
end
```

You can also add association between projects and teacher. And user `teacher.projects` if you need.

Comment: Actually, it is a `rails_admin` application where we need to write only models; the controllers and views functionality is done/generated by the `gem rails_admin`. Thus, customising the controller for a `rails_admin` application is not feasible.

Answer (score 0):

There is also another approach to achieve the functionality

create a new column called role in users table

```
     create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
        t.string   "email",                  default: "",    null: false
        t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "",    null: false
        t.string   "reset_password_token"
        t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
        t.datetime "remember_created_at"
        t.integer  "sign_in_count",          default: 0,     null: false
        t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
        t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
        t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
        t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
        t.datetime "created_at",                             null: false
        t.datetime "updated_at",                             null: false
        t.integer  "role"
        t.index ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true, using: :btree
        t.index ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true, using: :btree
      end
```

And in the user model

```
     class User < ApplicationRecord

      enum role: [:student, :teacher, ]
      after_initialize :set_default_role, :if => :new_record?

     def set_default_role
     self.role ||= :student
     end

     end
```

This creates a default role as student when a new user signs up.you can change the role of the user to teacher by simply doing

go to rails console in the terminal using
  **rails c**

```
  u = User.find_by_id(1) 
  # you can change value '1' depending upon your user_id
  u.role = "teacher"
  u.save
```

Now the role of the user is teacher.

```
  class ProjectsController < ApplicationController

  if current_user.teacher?
    @projects = Project.all
  else
    @project = current_user.projects
  end
```

Comment: Since it is a `rails_admin` application, the controller cannot be modified since both controller and view are generated by the `gem rails_admin`. Thus, I need a method to filter the data in the model itself.

Answer (score 0):

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :role
    has_many :projects

    def projects
        if self.role.to_s == "student"
            super projects
        else
            Project.all
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please review [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Code-only answers are discouraged because they do not explain how they resolve the issue in the question. You should update your answer to explain what this does and how it will help the OP.

Answer (score 0):

The answers provided asume the controllers can be changed and as the questioner points he does not have access to them.

Not sure if cancancan will handle the filtering of records based on view(read) permission on the index views of rails admin with a rule like this:

```
can :read, Project, user_id: user.id
```

But on the edit view i know you can configure a has many field to scope it based on the current user like this:

```
    edit do
      field :projects do
        associated_collection_scope do
          current_user = bindings[:controller].current_user
          proc { |scope| scope.where(user: current_user) }
        end
      end
    end
```

Comment: Thanks man, I worked on your suggestion based on the cancan gem. With slight modification I was able to get the desired result. I'll post my solution as an answer.